# Including an external header file in Flex

Tags: c++, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am writing a program using flex that takes input from a text file and splits them into some tokens like identifier, keywords, operators etc. My file name is test.l. I have made another hash table program which includes a file named SymbolTable.h . Is there any way to include this header file in my test.l file so that I can make some operations (for example: inserting the identifiers into the hash table)while reading the input? I have already tried to include it but when I try to compile using `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl` , it generates an error message saying:

> "fatal error: SymbolTable.h: No such file or directory."

Please help me on how to include the header file or in any other way I can do the desired operation I stated above.

Comment: You say that your header file is `SymbolTable.h` and later that the error says `SymbolInfo.h`. That sounds like you've put the wrong file name. It would be useful if you include in your answer so more details, including an excerpt from the `test.l` file where the header file is included.

Comment: sorry, edited. that was another file name I had mistakenly typed. Now check the post please @rici

Comment: I include the headers file in my lexer all the time and it was never a problem to use declared structures from them... Are you sure, like rici suggested, its not a path issue?

Comment: yap. I have edited the post @ Wojciech Frohmberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple application you can use a little template of bison/yacc project of mine.

gram.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

%}
// tokens here


%%
// rules here


%%

int main() {
   return yyparse();
}
```

scan.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

//include a YACC grammar header
//#include "gram.h"
%}
%%
. /*LEX RULES*/;

%%
// C code
int yywrap() {
   return 1;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: gram

gram: gram.c gram.h scan.c
    gcc gram.c scan.c -lfl -ly -o gram
gram.c: gram.y
    yacc -d gram.y -o gram.c
scan.c: scan.l
    flex -o scan.c scan.l

scan: scan.c
    gcc scan.c -lfl -o scan
```

Scanner uses the header file generated from bison in this example. But surely you can include in the same place some other header file.

To compile your lexer just type `make scan` or just `make` to compile lexer and grammar at the same time.

Have a good luck in your lexer journey!

Answer (score 2):

It seems your issue is not with flex, but with how the **C** language handles the different syntax. This is explained in this question: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).

You probably have:

```
#include <SymbolTable.h>
```

when you should have

```
#include "SymbolTable.h"
```

As you did not show the actual code you used it was hard to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your include statement worked just fine. The compiler couldn't find your file because it is not in the include search path. Try adding -I. when invoking gcc. Like : gcc -I.